# atualizar campo de lista sem refresh ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho a seguinte lista em jsp onde eu quero apenas incrementar o valor do campo quantidade, sem atualizar a página.

Do jeito que fiz, funciona, porém atualiza a página. Pelo que pesquisei, teria que ser por Ajax.

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <c:forEach items="${revistas}" var="r">
      <tr>
         <td>${r.nome }</td>
         <td>
            <form id="testeForm" action="<c:url value="/atualizaQuantidade"/>" method="post" >
               <input type="hidden" name="r.cod" id="cod" value="${r.cod}" />
               <input type="hidden" name="r.qtd" id="qtd" value="${l.qtd}" />
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">${r.qtd}</button>
            </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
      </c:forEach>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Como é uma lista, tenho que pegar o `id` da *revista*, a quantidade na lista e enviar para meu método Java pra incrementar (essa parte eu sei fazer). Agora fazer isso via Ajax, estou perdida. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Onde fica o ID da revista?

Comment: O valor do ID da revista obtenho através de ${r.cod}

Comment: @AmandaRJ coloquei um exemplo, com os parametros do formulário, caso seja outros, só informar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você deva trocar a tag form por um metodo ajax, junto a evento click de um Button

**Remova este trecho:**

```
     <td>
        <form id="testeForm" action="<c:url value="/atualizaQuantidade"/>" method="post" >
           <input type="hidden" name="r.cod" id="cod" value="${r.cod}" />
           <input type="hidden" name="r.qtd" id="qtd" value="${l.qtd}" />
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">${r.qtd}</button>
        </form>
     </td>
```

**Adicione este:**

```
  <td>
      <button data-cod="${r.cod}" data-qtd="${r.qtd}" class="btn btn-primary btn-qtd-click">${r.qtd}</button>
 </td>
```

**Por fim o seguinte js, usando jQuery:**

```
$(".btn-qtd-click).click(function(){ //Click no botão
    var $this = $(this); //Referência do botão que foi clicado

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/atualizaQuantidade", //Url do serviço POST
       data: {//Valores que o serviço recebe
          cod: $this.attr("data-cod"), //Usando atributo adicionado no html
          qtd: $this.attr("data-qtd"),
       },
      //dataType: dataType 
    }).done(function(){
        //FAca algo aqui se ocorrer tudo certo

        //Exemplo, atualizando o valor informado no button
        //$this.html(Nova quantidade)

    }).fail(function(){
         //Faça algo caso falhe
    })
 });
```